# Posso usar muitos IF's no PHP?

Tags: php, if, csv

Estou fazendo um projeto em que preciso criar um csv a partir de uma tabela do mysql, para criar o csv preciso seguir as normas de documentos do tipo, quando fui escrever o código percebi que ele iria possuir muitos if's para a adaptação do banco, isso se da por conta da quantidade de campos presentes no csv, queria saber se tem problema encher o while que preenche o csv de condições ou existe uma maneira mais fácil de fazer isso.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo do início do código

Comment: ja processa isso no mysql. usa o comando CASE pra isso

Comment: Acho que não tem problema. Porque, pelo seu código, vc não necessita usar tantos if's assim. Só acho que o seu segundo e terceiro IF's você poderia deixar assim if($row['RG_ORGAO'] = "SSPSP"){$c = "TESTE";} else if {empty($row['RG_ORGAO'])}{$c = "vazio";}. Poderia também utilizar um ELSE (Se for o caso) logo depois, para o caso de as condições do seu IF e do seu ELSE IF não forem atendidas.

Answer (score 0):

Não há problemas em usar vários `ifs`

Porém, neste teu caso em especifico, além de ter a opção de utilizar um `switch case`, também podes optar por utilizar `operador tenário`

**Exemplo:**

**Como seria em IF**

```
  $z = $row['sexo']; 
  if ($z == 'M')
  {
    $z = '1';
  }
  else
  {
    $z = "2";
  }   
  echo $z;
```

**Como seria em Operador Tenário**

```
$z = $row['sexo']; 
$z = $z == 'M' ? "2" : "1";
```